# How to read excel files containing brackets in header in sas?

Tags: sas

I have an excel file where open of the columns is temperature (F) and then when I import it in sas it saves variable name as temperature_F_ or when I use validvarany option it saves exactly as temperature (F). However, I need to now convert the data in C. So whenever I use either of the variable name (i.e temperature_F_ or temperature (F)) it does not work. For the second one, it thinks temperature as functions. So wats the way around this one?

Answer (score 1):

The exact nature of your problem isn't clear, as `temperature_F_` should be fine if you've imported under `validvarname=v7`.

```
data want;
  set have;
  temperature_c_ = (5/9)*((temperature_f_)-32);
run;
```

If you have to work with the `validvarname=any;` version, then you use named literals:

```
data want;
  set have;
  'temperature(c)'n =  (5/9)*(('temperature(f)'n)-32);
run;
```

Similar to a date literal (ie, `'01JAN2010'd`) but for member/variable/etc. names.